# Не полностью прокручивается scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

Я никак не могу понять как правильно использовать ScrollView вместе с автолайяутом. Я нашёл в некоторых уроках хитрости - надо чтобы внутри скроллвью был контейнер view в котором и будут храниться все элементы, а также надо привязать ширину этого контейнера к общему view. Я вроде бы это сделал.

У меня в общем View вставлен ScrollView, констрейнтами он полностью прилеплен к краям. Внутрь ScrollView вставлен View, который констрейнтами прилеплен к границам ScrollView. Так же я связал общий View и внутренний View констрейнтом EqualsWidth. И вроде бы при запуске всё работает, если потянуть вьюшку, то она скролится. Но если прокрутить слегка вниз, то не все элементы попадают в поле видимости. Часть элементов остаётся внизу за экраном. Также интересный факт, если потянуть вверх вьюшку, то все эти элементы показываются полностью на экране (те что раньше не влазили), но если отпустить, оно обратно отскакивает за пределы экрана вниз.

Верхние элементы показываются отлично. Я также пробовал задавать высоту содержимого для scrollView из кода:

```swift
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.scrollview.contentSize.height = 1500
    }
```

Я это сначала вставлял в viewDidLoad, это не дало результата, потом в viewWillAppear, но тоже никакого результата. Посоветуйте что делать?

Красной линией я отметил уровень по который прокручивается контент, ниже этой линии элементы не влазят.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел вот [этот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjTS9fyWqdg) урок и всё встало на свои места.
Порядок действий такой:

1. Добавляем scrollView в наш супервью (View)
2. Добавляем констрейнты lead, trealing, top, bottom
3. Добавляем в scrollView ещё view (назовём его например contentView)
4. Задаём ему констрейнты lead, trealing, top, bottom и ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО - height констрейнту, где мы устанавливаем высоту, которая будет равна высоте содержимого этой вьюхи
5. Привязываем констрейнтой equal widhts ширину contentView к View
   Всё.